# tikz: how to draw a fat arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

In order to draw a fat arrow with tikz I try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Triangle, very thick](0, 0) -- (1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I am not particularly impressed by the fatness of this arrow. I would like to draw a much fatter arrow as shown in the picture below:

[image]

How to draw such a fat arrow?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are already using `arrows.meta`, so you can adjust the parameters of the arrow. In particular, you can adjust `length` and `width`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-{Triangle[width=18pt,length=8pt]}, line width=10pt](0,0) -- (1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe that this will provide you with all possible triangle shaped arrows. You could define a scalable variant that scales with the line width,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my triangle/.style={-{Triangle[width=\the\dimexpr1.8\pgflinewidth,length=\the\dimexpr0.8\pgflinewidth]}}]
\draw[line width=6pt,my triangle](0,0) -- (1, 0); 
\draw[line width=10pt,my triangle](2,0) -- (3, 0);
\draw[line width=6pt,-{Triangle[width=1.8*6pt,length=0.8*6pt]}](0,-1)
-- (1, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many other arrows, and if the one you are looking for is not in the predefined list, you can always define your owe with `\pgfdeclarearrow`. However, here I do not think this is necessary.