# tikz: how to draw a fat arrow, specifying border and fill colour

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am evolving on [tikz: how to draw a fat arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518762/tikz-how-to-draw-a-fat-arrow)

I would like to specify the border and fill colour of the fat arrow.

I try:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue, fill=green, -{Triangle[width = 18pt, length = 8pt]}, line width = 10pt] (0.0, 0.0) -- (1.0, 0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is an arrow in one colour:

[image]

What to add?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As `single arrow` shape:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[single arrow, draw=blue, fill=green, 
      minimum width = 10pt, single arrow head extend=3pt,
      minimum height=10mm] {}; % length of arrow
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
drawing of arrows with shape is not so versatile as with simple line. For example it can't be bended,  for change of its direction you need to rotate it:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[single arrow, draw=blue, very thick, fill=green,
      minimum width = 10pt, single arrow head extend=3pt,
      minimum height=10mm,
      rotate=45] {}; % length of arrow
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Between to coordinates you can draw it with some precaution with help of `fit` library ...

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[pin=a] (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate[pin=b] (b) at (1,0);
\node[single arrow, draw=blue, very thick, fill=green,
      minimum width = 10pt, single arrow head extend=3pt,
      inner xsep=0pt,
      fit=(a) (b)] {}; % length of arrow
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more versatile arrows, you may consider to draw two arrows of different thickness: thinner over thicker:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw=blue,   line width=2mm, -{Triangle[length=6mm, bend]}]    
        (0,0) to [bend left]    (2,2);
\path[draw=green, line width=1mm, -{Triangle[length=4mm, bend]}, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=0.5mm]    
        (0,0) to [bend left]    (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, in above MWE you need to do some fine adjustment of arrows head (now I didn't bother with this) that "border" of combined arrows has the same thickness everywhere.

[image]

Comment: How could I control the border width?

Comment: @Viesturs, with options as `thick`, `very thick` etc, or by `line width=<width>`.

Comment: And how can I draw the arrow from the bottom to top or from coordinate `(3.0, 1.0)` to `(1.0, -2.0)`?

Comment: @Viesturs, see addendum to answer.